# Check if files are present on same server asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-io

I am working on Asp.net Website. I want to check if file are there on same server deployed application. How can i check that by physical path or virtual path ?

Eg: My website is deployed on Server A in directly Web1 which is under D drive.
I have one more website deployed on same server but different directory WEB2.There is folder in WEB2 directory say attachment ,which have all the media files eg pdf,doc etc.

So how can i check from Web1 that files are there in WEB2/Attachment folder ??

Answer (score 0):

If they're on the same server, you can use File.Exists(file..)

If they're on different servers but still within the same network, map a drive or use UNC format when using File.Exists

If they're on different servers with no way of being able to see each other's drives, create a webservice within each site; add a method that takes a filename as a parameter, the webservice itself can do a File.Exists

Comment: Files are on same server but problem is how to get path of other directory from my application.All i know is that there is folder name with attachment folder that contains media files. So do i have to find actual path or virtual path as both application will be deployed to server

Comment: Make the path of the other directory configurable, and expose that over a webservice method as well ?

Comment: I would hard code the actual path in the code to access the web2\attachment folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application pool has access to the attachment folder. I think the app pool by default doesn't have access to a folder outside the web1 directory. Then you can execute the following code to get the list of files in the attachment folder.

```
string[] fullPathToFiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\web2\attachment\")
```

or you can execute

```
File.Exists("D:\web2\attachment\<file.pdf>")
```

as sh1rts has suggested.